# Issue: variable is not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have a problem with simple typescript code. I'm trying to map object to string and the result is unexpected, the method always returns 'desc'. I was trying to debug the code and one thing is strange, that id variable is not defined. When I was trying to log 'state[0].id' on the console the correct value was printed. Thanks for the help!

```
interface Pageable {
   id: string,
   desc: boolean
}

private mapSortedToSortingString(state: Pageable[]): string {
    if (state.length > 0) {
        let id: string = state[0].id;
        let sort = id + ',' + (state[0].desc) ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        console.log(sort);
    }

    return (state.length > 0) ? (state[0].id + ',' + (state[0].desc) ? 'desc' : 'asc') : "";
}
```

[image: Console screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Only a partial answer, but needed formatting.)

Your ternary will be incorrect anyway due to operator precedence.

Put parens around your ternaries, e.g., the first one:

```
    const sort = id + ',' + ((state[0].desc) ? 'desc' : 'asc');
```

Or do it more legibly and break it out as an intermediate variable.

---

Unrelated, but as it's not reassigned, use `const`.

As to why it's `undefined`, we can't see your data, so we don't know. Is it coming in async (in which case `console.log` can be misleading)?

Comment: The id is still undefined, but with this, I can solve the problem, thanks! When I print the 'state[0].id' before 'id' declaration then the value is printed correctly, but 'id' variable is always undefined, this is strange.